# Clarifications in definition of $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, definition

I was reading the definition of $\sigma-$algebra and I wonder if $F=X$ ?

I think about this because in the definition we see that $F\in X$  and in $1.$ is the other contention.

But if I am correct, then 1. doesn't have so much sense, why do mathematicians mention this then?

> Let $X$ be a set. Then a $\sigma-$algebra $F$ is a nonempty collection of subsets of $X$ such that
>
> 1. $X$ is in $F$
> 2. $A$ is in $F$, then $A^c$ in $F$
> 3. If $A_n$ is a sequence of elements of $F$, then $\bigcup A_n$ is in $F$.

Comment: Why would $F=X$???  I have no idea what "in the definition we see that $F\in X$  and in $1.$ is the other contention" means.  The definition does not say that $F\in X$, and in any case $F\in X$ would imply that $F\neq X$.

Comment: $X$ is a set; $F$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. They cannot be equal.

Comment: In the first line of the definition, says F collection of subsets **of** X. In the second line says: X is **in** F @EricWofsey

Comment: $\in$ and $\subset$ mean very different things. For example, if $X = [0,2]$, we could have $F = \{\varnothing, [0,1], (1,2], [0,2] \}$. Then $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. We have $X \in F$ but not $X \subset F$.

Comment: $F$ is a subset of the power set of $X$ rather than a subset of $X$. That is, $F$ is a set of subsets of $X$ rather than a subset of $X$.

Comment: @User8128 oh, what a clear example to understand well the definition, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing $\in$ and $\subset$ (or $\in$ and $\subseteq$). $F$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. That is, $F \subseteq P(X)$, the *power set* of $X$. "$X$ is in $F$" is an informal way of saying "$X\in F$".

Comment: where did you learn to interpret that $F$ is a collection of subsets of $X\iff F\subset P(X)$ ?

Comment: I don't think I know how to answer that question! Are you asking why it's true, or how I developed the intuition to know immediately that it was true? If the latter: lots of practice and experience.

Comment: :) I was thinking in a book maybe, where did you see this always holds?

Comment: I didn't read it in a book, or at least I don't remember doing so. It's just a rephrasing that I came up with from experience. Sorry!

Comment: but it's not that clear to see that equivalence, since $X$ is an arbitrary set, i.e. can contain everything like _collections_, many collections, points, functions maybe

Comment: I think "collection" here is being used as a synonym for "set".